# XML Parsing through SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml-parsing

I have data stored in AuditTable named 'Audit' where Audit column named 'audit' has data stored in XML format. Below is the format of the XML formatted data.

```
<audit><Item CreatedDate="0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z" TypeOfData="UserName" PreviousValue="David" NewValue="Harry"></Item></Audit>
```

Please help me to get CreatedDate, PreviousValue and NewValue from this XML data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
DECLARE @xml XML ='<Audit><Item CreatedDate="0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z" TypeOfData="UserName" PreviousValue="David" NewValue="Harry"></Item></Audit>'

SELECT CreatedDate = T.value('@CreatedDate', 'varchar(100)'),
       PreviousValue = T.value('@PreviousValue', 'varchar(100)'),
       NewValue = T.value('@NewValue', 'varchar(100)')
FROM   @xml.nodes('/Audit/Item') tc (T)
```

**Note :** There is a mistake in your sample `xml`. Start tag(`audit`) and end tag(`Audit`) did not match I have fixed it.

**Update :** To extract the xml data from table use `Cross Apply`

```
CREATE TABLE #Audit (audit XML)

INSERT INTO #Audit
VALUES      ('<Audit><Item CreatedDate="0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z" TypeOfData="UserName" PreviousValue="David" NewValue="Harry"></Item></Audit>')

SELECT CreatedDate = T.value('@CreatedDate', 'varchar(100)'),
       PreviousValue = T.value('@PreviousValue', 'varchar(100)'),
       NewValue = T.value('@NewValue', 'varchar(100)')
FROM   #Audit
       CROSS apply audit.nodes('/Audit/Item') tc (T)
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing my mistake. I need a solution where I can pull records from table directly, assigning value to variable and then parsing from that I have done. Can you please help me there ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked. I just have a query, can't I use it directly on my base table ? I believe it's not working because data stored under my base table is stored on nvarchar format.

Comment: Error Message is, "The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml."

Comment: @Prasad - datatype of `audit` column should be of `xml` type. Use `Cast` or `Convert` to explicilty convert the `audit` column to xml but it will throw error if have any bad xml data in `audit` column